# Is it possible to put a variable title into a Microsoft SSRS Report Builder 1.0 report?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

For instance, I would like to have the title be "{Current Year} -- Total Sales"

It doesn't seem possible... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try an expression as follows:

```
=Year(Today) & " Total Sales"
```

I am using similar in report footers to generate the current year for copyright info.